# Line feeds (0x0A) transform into carriage returns (0x0D) during email file transfer

Tags: macos, file, email, newline

I’m sending a file via email from a Mac (Snow Leopard) to another Mac (Lion).

It turns out that all the line feeds (0x0A) in the file transform into carriage returns (0x0D), effectively turning the original file into a completely different file.

Any ideas why something like this would take place?

This does *not* happen when the sender upload the file to the web, and the recipient then downloads the file using his web browser. It also doesn’t happen if the sender first ZIPs the file and sends it via email; the recipient gets the original file intact after unzipping the ZIP file. Is there something special about email transfers I should know about?

Comment: Does this relate to programming in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for "send windows friendly attachments" in help, then turn the option off.

Comment: I thought Windows had *both* line feeds and carriage returns to represent new lines. In my case, one transforms into the other, and the byte size of the file stays exactly the same. Hmmm...

Comment: Interesting. I still think the "windows friendly attachments" option is the first thing to check.

Comment: Okay, I tried sending the file to myself both with and without the "windows friendly" option, and in both cases I get the original file back intact. So it looks like this "windows friendly" option is not it. Now, I'm not sure what my email client the other Lion user is using. Interesting...